# React-Js - Making POST request using useEffect and

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new in React-Js,I have a register page that i want to send a Post request to my backend .
UseState is working andeverything else,my method is handleSubmit .How do is use useEffect from here either by using axios or fetch?

```
export default function SignUp() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [passowrd, setPassowrd] = useState('');
 
 const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  }

 return (
    <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `useEffect`? Isn't the trigger condition "When the form is submitted"?

Comment: also, please add handleSubmit

Comment: I was searching online and i saw a lot of guys using that ,i am open for any answer

Comment: is it mandatory to use **useEffect** for making api call ? you can make api call in **handleSubmit** function itself.

Comment: Exactly. useEffect is for reacting to state/props change

Comment: If you want to use useEffect to run some async code you need to call that async function in that useEffect like `useEffect(() => { myAsyncFunction() },[])`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the useEffect Hook, as you are not performing it on component load/change.
instead use async/promise with function handleSubmit

```js
export default function SignUp() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [passowrd, setPassowrd] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async () =>{ 
    const res = await axios.post('YOUR BACKEND',{
    username,email,password
    })
  }
  
  //remember to handle change for form inputs
 return (
    <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    </>
  )
```